# DateTime in a TimeZone which is not UTC or Local

Tags: c#, datetime

I have question pertaining to the `DateTimeKind` struct in C#.

If I have converted a `DateTime` to a new DateTime (which is not in my local Timezone) using something like:

```
TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeBySystemTimeZoneId(now, "Tokyo Standard Time");
```

what should I use for the `Kind` property of that new DateTime? `Unspecified` feels a bit weird and does not help much with conversions.

I get the feeling that as soon as you use a `Timezone` which is not your local and not UTC, then you absolutely have to start using the `DateTimeOffset` struct.

Comment: I think I have found the answer I need. If you do something like `TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeBySystemTimeZoneId(now, "Fiji Standard Time", "AUS Eastern Standard Time");`, that only works where the `Kind` is `Unspecified`.

Comment: Utc datetime also works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> what should I use for the Kind property of that new DateTime? `Unspecified` feels a bit weird...

...but it's the correct value in this case. [The documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetimekind?view=net-6.0) of the DateTimeKind enum is quite clear on this subject:

> **Local** (2): The time represented is local time.
>
> **Unspecified** (0): The time represented is not specified as either local time or Coordinated Universal Time (UTC).
>
> **Utc** (1): The time represented is UTC.

Your time is neither local time nor UTC, so the only correct value is `Unspecified`.

> I get the feeling that as soon as you use a Timezone which is not your local and not UTC, then you absolutely have to start using the `DateTimeOffset` struct.

You don't have to, but it can definitely make your life easier. As you have noticed, `DateTime` does not provide an option to store the time zone information along with the date. This is exactly what `DateTimeOffset` is for.

Comment: I agree with your answer and will mark it as such. I've provided a long-form answer as well which basically reached the same conclusion with examples. By all means , please take a look at that and let me know if I have stated anything that it patently wrong. Thanks.

Comment: @onefootswill: I like your answer!

Answer (score 2):

This is more a question about how to handle non-local TimeZones.
When you go beyond your local timezone, you really do need to use the `DateTimeOffset` class.

When writing a time service, you may want to add a method for converting a DateTime in one non-local timezone to another non-local timezone. This is pretty straight forward when using the `DateTimeOffset` class:

```
public DateTimeOffset ConvertToZonedOffset(DateTimeOffset toConvert, string timeZoneId)
{
    var universalTime = toConvert.ToUniversalTime(); // first bring it back to the common baseline (or standard)

    var dateTimeOffset = TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTime(universalTime, TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById(timeZoneId));
    
    return dateTimeOffset;
}
```

The incoming `DateTimeOffset` has the source offset and the `timeZoneId` being passed in gives enough information to realize the target timezone (and offset).

And the returned `DateTimeOffset` has the target offset.

It gets a bit clunkier when you do it with the `DateTime` struct, if you wanted to provide an equivalent method:

```
public DateTime ConvertToZonedOffset(DateTime toConvert, string sourceTimeZoneId, string targetTimeZoneId)
{
    return TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeBySystemTimeZoneId(toConvert, sourceTimeZoneId, targetTimeZoneId);
}
```

And this is where the `DateTimeKind` comes in. If you:

- pass the DateTime in with the Kind set to either UTC or Local; **AND**
- the sourceTimeZone is neither of those,

then `ConvertTimeBySystemTimeZoneId` will throw an exception. So, when you are dealing with a "3rd timezone", Kind must be `Unspecified`. This tells the method to ignore the system clock, to not assume that it is UTC and to go by whatever is passed in as the sourceTimeZone.

It's not as good as the `DateTimeOffset` version in another way. The returned `DateTime` has no information about the timezone and the `Kind` is set to `Unspecified`. This basically means that it is the responsibility of the calling code to know and track what timezone that date and time is valid in. Not ideal. So much so that I decided to "be opinionated" and get rid of that method. I'll force the calling code to convert the `DateTime` they may be  working with to a `DateTimeOffset` and to consume one upon return.

Note 1: if `Kind` is set to `Local` and the sourceTimeZone matches your local timezone, it will work fine.
Note 2: if `Kind` is set to `Utc` and the sourceTimeZone is set to "Coordinated Universal Time", you may get the following `TimeZoneNotFoundException`:

> The time zone ID 'Coordinated Universal Time' was not found on the local computer

I assume that this is because UTC is a standard and not a timezone, despite being returned by `TimeZoneInfo.GetSystemTimeZones` as a `Timezone`.